# Complex query with multiple solutions from c ++

Tags: c++, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I’m using: SWI-Prolog version 8.0.3-1 for Microsoft Windows (64 bit)
Simple example:

```
parent(pam,bob).
parent(tom,bob).
parent(tom,liz).
parent(bob,ann).
parent(bob,pat).
parent(pat,jim).
```

I want to use the c ++ interface to access the database, get all the available solutions and then manipulate them in c ++.
I found the PlQuery and PlCall class descriptions in the manual. But I do not understand how to execute such a request with their help.

```
parent(tom,X),parent(X,Y).
```

PlCall looks very good but it does not display all the solutions.
Any ideas …

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: This has an answer [here](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/complex-query-with-multiple-solutions-from-c/894/3)